# How should you access controller functions from other modules

Tags: angularjs

I am having a hard time understanding how Modules should interact with each other in Angularjs.  I would like to break the application into nice small modules, but I cannot seem to find the correct way to have these modules interact with each other.

**JSFiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/jwest80/o5o3sr8q/4/**

The code shows a breadcrumb I would like to have at the top of the page.  The BreadCrumb is in its own module 'bread' and included inside a parent module 'ngFSCH'.

There is a list outside BreadCrumb controller section whose actions should add breadcrumbs.  However, I do not understand the correct way to access this addCrumb function.  I can only make it work if it is called from inside the breadcrumb controller section in the markup.

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-app="ngFSCH">

    <section ng-controller="BreadCrumbsCtrl">
        <span ng-repeat="crumb in crumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
            <span ng-hide="isLast($index)" ng-click="selectCrumb($index)"><a href="#">{{crumb.text}}</a> > </span>
            <span ng-show="isLast($index)">{{crumb.text}}</span>
        </span>
    </section>


    <section>
        <h4>Add Some Crumbs</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="BreadCrumbsCtrl.addCrumb('Company')">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="BreadCrumbsCtrl.addCrumb('Department')">Department</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="BreadCrumbsCtrl.addCrumb('User')">User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>

</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var ngFSCH = angular.module('ngFSCH', ['bread']);

(function () {
    var app = angular.module('bread', []);

    app.controller('BreadCrumbsCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {

        $scope.crumbs = [{ text: "Crumb 1", url: "url1" }, { text: "Crumb 2", url: "url2" }];

        $scope.isLast = function(index) {
            return index === $scope.crumbs.length-1;
        }

        $scope.addCrumb = function (newCrumb) {
            $scope.crumbs.push({ text: newCrumb, url: "TestURL" });
        }

        $scope.selectCrumb = function (index) {
            $log.info($scope.crumbs[index].url);
            $scope.crumbs = $scope.crumbs.slice(0, index + 1);
        }


    }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encapsulate the bread crumb functionality in a service and create a controller for the section with the links (that add the breadcrumbs). The new controller can then use the service to add and remove crumbs from the array. You can also add the crumbs array into a value.. Your controllers can then expose the add and select features to the tiny portions of html they control without polluting other sections of your page.

Here is the result. Hope it helps!

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zjg4nsgk/1/)

**Here is the code:**

```
var app = angular.module('bread', []);

app.value('crumbs',  [
    { text: "Crumb 1", url: "url1" }, 
    { text: "Crumb 2", url: "url2" }
]);

app.factory("BreadCrumbsService", ['$log', 'crumbs', function ($log, crumbs) {
    var service = {
        getCrumbs: getCrumbs,
        addCrumb: addCrumb,
        selectCrumb: selectCrumb
    };
    return service;

    //I did not add a set crumbs because you can set it directly.
    function getCrumbs(){
        return crumbs;
    } 

    function addCrumb(newCrumb) {
        crumbs.push({
            text: newCrumb,
            url: "TestURL"
        });
    }

    function selectCrumb(index) {
        $log.info(crumbs[index].url);
        crumbs = crumbs.slice(0, index + 1);
    }        
}]);

app.controller('BreadCrumbsCtrl', ['$scope', 'BreadCrumbsService', function ($scope, BreadCrumbsService){
    $scope.crumbs = BreadCrumbsService.getCrumbs;
    $scope.selectCrumb = BreadCrumbsService.selectCrumb;
    $scope.isLast = function (index) {
        return index === BreadCrumbsService.getCrumbs().length - 1;
    }
}]);


app.controller('AddLinksCtrl', ['$scope', 'BreadCrumbsService', function ($scope, BreadCrumbsService) {
    $scope.addCrumb = BreadCrumbsService.addCrumb;
}]);
```

**Here is the links section with the new controller:**

```
 <section ng-controller="AddLinksCtrl">
        <h4>Add Some Crumbs</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="addCrumb('Company')">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="addCrumb('Department')">Department</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ng-click="addCrumb('User')">User</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be more inline with what I was looking for.  My time has been pulled elsewhere at the moment, but I will get back to this shortly.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance - shout if anything is unclear.

Comment: Stefan, I noticed one issue.  When calling 'selectCrumb', the crumbs array is updated, but the screen is not.  I still see the previous list.  Do I have to apply this data change somehow?

Comment: Yes my bad. So what was happening is that the view was still referencing the old unsliced array while the value was updated. I fixed this by adding a getter in the service. This way the view will get a reference to what is currently in the crumbs value even if it was replaced since the previous $digest loop.

Comment: You could technically ditch the service and place the add and select functions in the controllers directly but i believe it is best practice to encapsulate it in a service. This way, when you need to add a crumb from yet another place(controller/service/etc.) you can just inject the BreadCrumbsService and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you, The learning curve on this Angular stuff is feeling a little steeper than I originally expected.  However, I think this will be very helpful moving forward.

Comment: Additionally, the ability to inject the module or service in this case is exactly what I was trying to figure out.  Everything I was reading pointed out how angular should be broken into small modules that could be reused.  This is the only clean approach I have seen that makes that possible.

Answer (score 1):

That is intended because you are working within the scope of the controller.  How about moving the ng-controller directive to the containing div where ng-app is?

```
<div ng-app="ngFSCH" ng-controller="BreadCrumbsCtrl">
```

Comment: And also remove the prefix 'BreadCrumbsCtrl' on the calls to addCrumb, since they are on the $scope.

Comment: So if I am adding additional modules on the page, does this mean I will be moving all my controllers up to the parent div?  I am beginning to feel as if all my little modules should just be one large module.

Comment: Not necessarily.  In your instance, though, you are creating and displaying breadcrumbs, so logically it makes sense that they are all handled by some sort of breadcrumb controller.  The modular approach works really well with Angular so definitely don't just make everything one big module.

Comment: I may not have been as clear as I hoped, but the bread crumb code above is an example.  What i am trying to understand better is how these smaller modules interact.  I am trying to avoid moving everything inside the ng-controller.